# Application crashed after either receive a phone call or such interruptions

Tags: android, android-progressbar, android-logcat

After I either receive a phone call or make one, (and other undocumented interruptions) my application gets a **NullPointerException** when resuming my activity. Can any explain to me where it is and/or how to fix it?

I have written the code as shown below:

```
 @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.displayActivity);
        new performBackgroundTask().execute();
  }

  @Override
  public void onDestroy()
  {
    listview1.setAdapter(null);
    super.onDestroy();
  }

  private class performBackgroundTask extends AsyncTask <Void, Void, Void>  
  {
           private ProgressDialog Dialog = new ProgressDialog(displayActivity.this);

           protected void onPreExecute()
           {
               Dialog.setMessage(getString(R.string.dialog_wait_message));
               Dialog.show();
           }

           protected void onPostExecute(Void unused)    
           {
               Dialog.dismiss();    
               // displaying all the fetched data
           }

           @Override
            protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) 
            {
                 // fetching data from web using HTTPGet method 
                return null;   
        }
  }
```

### Logcat output is:

java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to destroy activity {myApplication/MyApplication.displayActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
at android.app.ActivityThread.performDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:3655)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:3673)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3789)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2400(ActivityThread.java:125)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2037)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at MyApplication.displayActivity.onDestroy(displayActivity.java:74)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:3642)

***now, pls help me to fix this problem, how do i handle phone call or SMS received or such kind of interruptions?***

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Step #1: Find line 74 of the `displayActivity.java` file.

Step #2: Fix whatever problem is on line 74.

Now, the stack trace suggests that line 74 is in `onDestroy()`. Assuming that the activity code you have listed above is from `displayActivity`, then line 74 must be:

```
listview1.setAdapter(null);
```

That means `listview1` is `null`. You neither declare nor assign a value to this data member in the code you have listed above.

Comment: thanx for the support, and on line 74 there is an ending brace "}" of onDestroy()

Comment: @Paresh Mayani: That suggests that your app is not running the same code as you are looking at, since you cannot crash with a `NullPointerException` on an ending curly brace. Also, `super` can't be `null`.

Comment: the problem is in listview1.setAdapter(null), but dont know why !! if i removed it then the application is running fine and not giving FORCE CLOSE alert box. by d way, thanx for support

Comment: @CommonsWare I have same problem, incoming call crash app, what is solution for this.

Comment: Hello..am extending service in my app..and it crashes after a phone call..how to i solve it

Answer (score 0):

try setting a BP at the first line of `onDestroy` and validate vars/members to find which one is `null`